# VerifyError after obfuscating a JAR file

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, allatori

I am currently trying to obfuscate my Java applications. I have already tried several obfuscators, such as ProGuard and Allatori. With both of them I get a VerifyError after the obfuscation.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: m/m/C, method: I signature: ()Lm/m/m/D;) Incompatible object argument for function call
    at v.m.m.t.m.f.I(w:346) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.t.m.f.ALLATORIxDEMO(w:14) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.m.i.f(hld:118) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.m.i.I(hld:48) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.m.c.ALLATORIxDEMO(idd:83) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.m.m.m.ALLATORIxDEMO(mmd:125) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.t.H.ALLATORIxDEMO(s:496) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.t.H.ALLATORIxDEMO(s:65) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.t.H.I(s:337) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.t.H.ALLATORIxDEMO(s:345) ~[?:?]
    at v.m.m.t.H.k(s:568) ~[?:?]
    at m.t.H.ALLATORIxDEMO(tda:229) ~[?:?]
    at m.t.H.<init>(tda:30) ~[?:?]
    at m.t.H.<init>(tda:111) ~[?:?]
    at m.t.H.<init>(tda:154) ~[?:?]
    at de.pluginstore.modularbungee.t.m.h.I(lmc:254) ~[?:?]
    at de.pluginstore.modularbungee.t.m.h.<init>(lmc:88) ~[?:?]
    at de.pluginstore.modularbungee.ModularBungee.ALLATORIxDEMO(zfc:114) ~[?:?]
    at net.md_5.bungee.scheduler.BungeeTask.run(BungeeTask.java:66) ~[bungee.jar:git:FlameCord-Bootstrap:1.17-R0.1-SNAPSHOT:752f972:unknown]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

With ProGuard it looked different than with Allatori. However, I think it's the same problem. I can't find anything about it. I am using Java 16.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use the Proguard Mappings file (or with Proguard ReTrace) and find what `v.m.m.t.m.f.I(w:346)`, and method `I` of class `m.m.C`, and class `m.m.m.D` correspond to. Paste the code of `v.m.m.t.m.f.I(w:346)` and which line is referencing the method `I`. Please also share which specific javac you are compiling with (or which specific JDK it came in). I think I've encountered something similar and might be able to help if I can see a bit of code.